# Find items in JArray by name/key

Tags: c#, json

I have JSON that looks similar to this:

```
[{“itemA”:{“name”:”foo”,”other”:"bar”}},{“itemB”:{“name”:”foo2”,”other”:”bar2”}},{“itemC”:{“name”:”foo3”,”other”:”bar3”}},{“itemB”:{“name”:”foo4”,”other”:”bar4”}}]
```

I have parsed it into a JArray object, but now I need to find specific objects in that array by name (i.e. "itemB"). I can't seem to find how to do this when the array is the root object.

I have tried the code below, but I only get back a null JToken.

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
JToken itemATkn = array.SelectToken("itemA");
```

I also need to be able to find multiple values (i.e. both "itemB" items in example above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
if (array.Count > 0) {
    JToken itemATkn = array[0]["itemA"];
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. The only issue was the "itemA" needs to be in square brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: @jpaull Nice catch. Fixed